# Notification system for Angular 2

Tags: angular, notifications

I need to start a project with Angular2 where I'll log in on a page as admin. Other people will visit the page and will be able to send notifications.

Let's say, as a regular user you can go to the page and fill some inputs like name, age, gender... This information should be sent as a notification to the admin page, so he will see something like a popup or a div container with this information.

Is there any resource you guys know that I should check to do that in Angular2?

Comment: "I need to..." isn't a valid question, it is a problem statement, which indicates that you are hoping others will provide you with solutions to a problem you haven't tried solving yourself.  This seems to be further re enforced by the follow up "Is there any resource...".  These type of questions are off topic here, because they tend to attract opinions or spam.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a front end Angular app and a backend server.

The front end app will send requests for info to backend via HTTP (or websockets if you prefer).

JSON web tokens are great for login procedures. NodeJS with the Express module is great for serving up a backend (either HTTP or websockets).

socket.io is an npm module used for websockets that is great for communicating when events have happened between clients.

You could mix up HTTP and websockets if you wanted.

Comment: Just going to point out that this answer has the same qualities that @Claies said such an answer would.